# Build Problem: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, build, syntax-error

#### Info:

The error is occurring with the build command `yarn run build`, returning this SyntarError, which is pointing to a node_modules file.
I didn't change any default settings.

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "controle-financeiro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^5.12.8",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

#### Error (terminal):

```
$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Skipping validation of types
 ✓ Linting
   Collecting page data  .G:\Dev\controle-financeiro\controle-financeiro\node_modules\rc-util\es\Children\toArray.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at mod.require (G:\Dev\controle-financeiro\controle-financeiro\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at 4393 (G:\Dev\controle-financeiro\controle-financeiro\.next\server\pages\controle-financeiro.js:1:848)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /controle-financeiro
    at G:\Dev\controle-financeiro\controle-financeiro\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1220:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

#### Tried:

1. Deleting node_modules and run `yarn install`;
2. Deleting .next folder and run `yarn build`;
3. Run `npm upgrade next` (up to date);

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for `controle-financeiro.js`?

Comment: I tried running antd on next v14 and had the same error. It’s works ok with v12.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is unique to next 14 and up, use with "antd". It happens when you're trying to use "import" to bring in extra code in Node.js. It's like trying to add a new method to your app, but sometimes the app doesn't know you want to use this new method.

Imagine you have a bookshelf with different shelves for books. If you don't tell the bookshelf that you want to add a new type of book (let's say, by mentioning "type='novel'"), it might not let you place and access the new books properly. So, it's important to tell the bookshelf about the new types of books you want to add!

In your case the type is a module. So, add "type": "module", to you package.json file and rebuild. Like this:

```
{
  "name": "your-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Your dependencies go here
  }
}
```

My guess is that you've updated to a new version of next. If adding the type doesn't work, use an alternative to "antd". Preferably, a dependency using a newer version of react.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I actually tried this before too, but got other erros as result.
Lately I found at ant design doc the properly bootstrap project command, I do believe that could make things possible buildable.
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next

This project is meant to be simple, so I recreated it, but this time with Vite.

Comment: Try downgrading you next to v12 or v13.